# Reading Python source code in Pycharm, specifically __builtin__.py

Tags: python, pycharm

I am searching through method/class declarations in Pycharm and I made it down to __builtin__.py, but there does not appear to be any code written in this module.

Here is the snippet that I came across:

```
def hasattr(p_object, name): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
    """
    hasattr(object, name) -> bool

    Return whether the object has an attribute with the given name.
    (This is done by calling getattr(object, name) and catching exceptions.)
    """
    return False
```

Where is the code that is actually executed when I call `hasattr()`? Is the line `# real signature unknown; restored from __doc__` a clue as to why there is no code here?

I am not interested in changing anything.  I am simply surprised that there is no code written here.

Comment: If you're using CPython, the underlying implementation isn't actually written in Python; it's C.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 1):

They are **built in** functions.

It means that they are a direct calls to methods embedded in python binaries. Simply, the python code for them doesn't exist.